# API returned information appear 1 sec on CodePen and disappeared. Why?

Tags: javascript, api

You are supposed to enter a zipde like 11362, and get 'Little Neck' under City Name. 'Little Neck' appear for a brife moment there in the CodePen window and disappear. Why?

I think I didnt make any midstake in my code. But I somehow type the API url wrong. I don't know. The information is there. The request is successful, well partially.

[My project.](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/WEbyva?editors=0010)

Code:

```js
var button=document.getElementById('submit');
var zipcode;

/*takes what the user enters*/
button.addEventListener('click',getValue);
function getValue(){
  zipcode=document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
  getCity();
}
//API request to Google Geocode 
function getCity(){
  var req=new XMLHttpRequest;
  req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){
      var myData=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var myCity=myData.results[0].address_components[1].short_name;
      document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=myCity;
    }//if function end
  }//onreadystate function end
  req.open('GET','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zipcode, true);
  req.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text placeholder='zipcode' id='zipcode'></input>
  <input type='submit' id='submit'></input>
</form>

<ol>
  <li>City Name: <span id='city'></span></li><br>
  
  <li>Temperature(C/F): <span id='temp'></span></li>
  <li>Icon: <span id='icon'></span></li>
  <li>Weather: <span id='weather'></span></li><br>
  <li>Wind: <span id='wind'></span></li>
  <li>Sunrise: <span id='sunrise'></span></li> 
  <li>Weather: <span id='sunset'></span></li>
</ol>
```

EDIT: Here, you click submit and it goes blank.

Answer (score 2):

The form submission is trying to make the request to the form action, in this case, there is no action, so the form will just reload the page.

That's why it's disappearing

You need to add :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in you click event listener you must prevent the default behavior in order to execute the code that is in the listener.

```
function getValue(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  zipcode=document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
  getCity();
}
```

```js
var button=document.getElementById('submit');
var zipcode;

/*takes what the user enters*/
button.addEventListener('click',getValue);
function getValue(event){
event.preventDefault();
  zipcode=document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
  getCity();
}
//API request to Google Geocode 
function getCity(){
  var req=new XMLHttpRequest;
  req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200){
      var myData=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var myCity=myData.results[0].address_components[1].short_name;
      document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=myCity;
    }//if function end
  }//onreadystate function end
  req.open('GET','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zipcode, true);
  req.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=text placeholder='zipcode' id='zipcode'></input>
  <input type='submit' id='submit'></input>
</form>

<ol>
  <li>City Name: <span id='city'></span></li><br>
  
  <li>Temperature(C/F): <span id='temp'></span></li>
  <li>Icon: <span id='icon'></span></li>
  <li>Weather: <span id='weather'></span></li><br>
  <li>Wind: <span id='wind'></span></li>
  <li>Sunrise: <span id='sunrise'></span></li> 
  <li>Weather: <span id='sunset'></span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why use parameter e? When the getValue function is called in the Event Handler, there is no parameter.

Comment: `e` is the `event` that it's being triggered (an event is always passed as a parameter to the listener function in your case `getValue', this event gives you information about the event that just happened ), in this case, the submit event as I mentioned in my answer by the default will reload the page since there is no action in your form, and you need to prevent the default behavior .

Comment: Then why isnt the eventlistener written like "button.addEventListener('click',getValue(event));"?

Comment: because `getValue` is a callback that `addEventListener` will call once the event has happend and also pass the `event` parameter if you do `getValue(event)` nothing will happen because it will return undefined (since you are not returning anything within the `getValue` function)

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default behavior of the submit button

```
function getValue(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  zipcode=document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
  getCity();
}
```

**P.S.**

`button.addEventListener('click',getValue);` here, `getValue` is a **reference** to the function called when the `button` event `click` is fired (a reference should not take params; think of it as a pointer to the function declaration). Once the `button` is `click`ed an event object is passed **by default** to your click handler `getValue`. when you define this function, you have access to the event object as param. You can give it any alias but the most common ones are `e` and `event`

`function getValue(yourEventAlias) {...}` and then if you want to prevent the default behavior of the submit button add `yourEventAlias.preventDefault();` to the body of your function.

Comment: Why use parameter e? When the getValue function is called in the Event Handler, there is no parameter.

Comment: @user132522: the event object is added by default to the handler `getValue`. `e` is an alias to that event

Comment: Then why isnt the eventlistener written like "button.addEventListener('click',getValue(event));"?

Comment: @user132522, I added some explanation, hope it helps you understand what's going on.